# Why is my if statement not executing when I start my code?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner programmer just starting out and learning and I'm wondering why my code finishes after the first line. If anyone can let me know what is wrong with it, would be greatly appreciated.

I wanted it to print my if statements properly but I'm not sure what's going on.

```
x = 10

try:
    (input("Type in a number:"))
except ValueError:
    print('Correct!')
    if x > 10:
        print('X is bigger than the number given')
    if x < 10:
        print('X is smaller than the number given')
```

Comment: If you were to parse the return value of `input()` to e.g. an `int` using `x = int(input("Type in a number:"))` you might get a value error if you enter an character, but then your logic still does not make much sense as the if only makes sense if `x` can be parsed as `int` or `float`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you stated that you're a new programmer (welcome! we've all been in your shoes at one point), I'm going to assume from looking at your code that the goal of your game is to have a "magic number" that is set ahead of time, and you want the user to try and guess it. In general, good programs are self-documenting, meaning the code is written in a way that clearly describes what it does. Comments are also helpful. Take a note of the changes I made to your program and how they help you understand what's going on:

```py
"""
* This comment is known as a module docstring
  and describes the module, the file in this case
* guessing_game.py is a command-line game
  where users try to guess a random number
  while getting hints about their guess.
"""

magic_number = 42  # set this before running the program

while (guess := int(input('enter a guess: '))) != magic_number:
    # * use a while loop to loop until the correct answer is entered.
    # NOTE: the "walrus operator `:=` is used for consiceness.
    #       the walrus operator requires python >= 3.8
    if guess > magic_number:
        print('Too high!')
    else:
        print('Too low!')
print('You win!')
```

Now, kuwl, I challenge you to try the following on your own:

1. generate `magic_number` automatically when the program starts.

   - hint: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html
2. Set a special number, called a "sentinel value" in computer science, that will terminate the loop if the user wants to quit before guessing the correct number.
3. Set a limit on the number of attempts the player can make before he/she "loses". This can be done in several ways, try and think of a few!
4. Allow users to quit the game with `ctrl-c`, which is a common way to exit command-line programs like yours. Try catching the exception that gets "thrown" when a users hits `ctrl-c` gracefully and print a message like "thanks for playing, come again!"

Those changes will introduce you to a lot of key concepts in programming like importing packages, handling exceptions, and writing comments and self-documenting code. If you get stuck, try googling your question. There's a good chance many others have asked the same before. It's a valuable skill in programming to be able to write good questions, both to a search engine and to another human. If you're still stuck, ask a comment on this post and I'll do my best to answer it.

Happy hacking!

Answer (score 0):

You will never get a ValueError in this program from this line `input("Type in a number:")`

Corrected code:

```
x = 10

try:
    x = input("Type in a number:")
    print('Correct!')

except ValueError:
    if x > 10:
        print('X is bigger than the number given')
    if x < 10:
        print('X is smaller than the number given')
```

You can simply do:

```
x = 10
x = input("Type in a number:")
if x.isnumeric() : # checks if x is numeric or not
   print('Correct!')

if x > 10:
   print('X is bigger than the number given')
if x < 10:
   print('X is smaller than the number given')
```